# tkinter option menu doesn't return the correct value for selected options created via .add_command()

Tags: python, tkinter

My very first tkinter experience was going rather smoothly, but now I'm stumped.

I received assistance, and got some modifed test code I found from another thread while researching. However, I couldn't get the code working in my actual project.

I'm trying to figure out why replacing
`menu['menu'].add_command(label='New Item')` with
`for x in ['d', 'e', 'f']: menu['menu'].add_command(label=x, command=lambda: callback(x))` breaks.

The last new entry added (f in this case) is always returned when one of the other newly created entries d or e is selected, while the initial entries a, b, & c continue to work as expected.

Working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(selection):
    print(selection)
    options.set(selection)

root = tk.Tk()
options = tk.StringVar()
menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, options, 'a', 'b', 'c', command=callback)
menu.pack()
menu['menu'].add_command(label='New Item', command=lambda: callback('New Item'))
options.set('a')
root.mainloop()
```

Broken example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(selection):
    print(selection)
    options.set(selection)

root = tk.Tk()
options = tk.StringVar()
menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, options, 'a', 'b', 'c', command=callback)
menu.pack()
for x in ['d', 'e', 'f']:
    menu['menu'].add_command(label=x, command=lambda: callback(x))
options.set('a')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `lambda: callback(x)` to `lambda x=x: callback(x)`

Comment: Right.  This is a cute little trap in Python.  As you have it, the `x` in your callback function refers to the loop variable, and when the loop ends, `x` is always 'f'.  To make this work, you need to "capture" the value of the variable.  That's what @TheLizzard is showing you.

Comment: @TimRoberts Great explanation. You should post it as an answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right. This is a cute little trap in Python. As you have it, the `x` in your callback function refers to the loop variable, and when the loop ends, `x` is always 'f'. To make this work, you need to "capture" the value of the variable. That's what @TheLizzard is showing you in

```
lambda x=x: callback(x)
```

The `x` in the lambda now refers to the parameter, and the parameter's default VALUE is captured when the lambda is created.